# How would you manipulate the data in an array and store the output into a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would you manipulate the data in an array and store the output into a new array using JavaScript?

For example, given an array with five numbers:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to manipulate the data, such as multiplying the numbers by 2. I'm able to output the results to the console:

```
for (i = 0; i < arrOne.length; i++) {
   console.log(arr[i]*2);
}  

console => 2,4,6,8,10
```

I want to store the output data into a new array, something like `arrTimesTwo = []`. How will I achieve this?

p.s. I can't seem to find an answer to what seems like a basic question. Please provide a source if this is redundant.

Comment: arrTimesTwo = arr.map(n => n*2)

Comment: Like, really…? `arrTimesTwo.push(arr[i] * 2)`…?!

Comment: A lot of JavaScript Array methods are available now. You can use `map` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each value to itself multiplied by 2, like so:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arrTimesTwo = arr.map(v => v * 2);
console.log(arrTimesTwo );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to push. `map` do it for you.

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const newArr = arr.map(item => item *2);
console.log(newArr);
```